# Various problems with Ruby stemming from Libyaml error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been trying to learn Ruby on Rails for quite a while now but I keep encountering the error

```
  It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.
```

I've tried reinstalling Ruby, Rails, RVM etc but I don't seem to be getting anywhere. I think it might be something to do with my profile or libyaml not being linked...I'm completely new so I'm not too sure.

Is it possible to remove all of my Rubies and start from a fresh? I've read this isn't a good idea but I can't see any other options. I think I've poked around too much and broken something, but I'm not sure what.

This is what brew doctor says:

```
Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:

    /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/curl-config
    /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/ncurses5-config
    /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/ncursesw5-config
    /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/pkg-config
    /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/xml2-config
    /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/xslt-config

Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
    /usr/local/lib/libltdl.7.dylib

Warning: Unbrewed .la files were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .la files:
    /usr/local/lib/libltdl.la

Warning: Unbrewed .pc files were found in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .pc files:
    /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/ruby-1.9.pc

Warning: Unbrewed static libraries were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected static libraries:
    /usr/local/lib/libltdl.a
    /usr/local/lib/libruby-static.a

Warning: You have a non-Homebrew 'pkg-config' in your PATH:
  /opt/sm/pkg/active/bin/pkg-config

`./configure` may have problems finding brew-installed packages using
this other pkg-config.
```

Got the following error when running dvm install libyaml:

```
Error running '__rvm_autoreconf -is --force', showing last 15 lines of /Users/andrewallsop/.rvm/log/1397549620/yaml_autoreconf.log and when running reinstall ruby:  Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_libs_install automake', showing last 15 lines of /Users/andrewallsop/.rvm/log/1397549715_ruby-2.1.1/package_install_automake.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the RVM procedure:

```
rvm pkg install libyaml
rvm reinstall 2.1.1 --with-libyaml-dir=/home/<your user>/.rvm/usr
```

Comment: Got the following error when running install libyaml:

`Error running '__rvm_autoreconf -is --force',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/andrewallsop/.rvm/log/1397549620/yaml_autoreconf.log`

and when running reinstall ruby: 

`Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_libs_install automake',
showing last 15 lines of /Users/andrewallsop/.rvm/log/1397549715_ruby-2.1.1/package_install_automake.log`

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled Mavericks. Too many errors, works perfectly now. My advice? Don't go installing and uninstalling Ruby without any knowledge.